# Navigation bar and tab bar turned black on iOS15 Xcode 13

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard, ios15

Today I just updated my Xcode to version 13 and found that all the navigation bars and the tab bars of my project turned black, I didn't change any settings, my project was working fine on Xcode 12, and I have toggled it to light mode, I couldn't find a way to recover the appearances to the old ones.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just simply check the "Translucent" in your attributes inspector.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Apply the following code to update the appearance of the navigation bar. This can be done in AppDelegate if you wish for it to be the appearance throughout the app.

```
let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
appearance.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: .black]
appearance.backgroundColor = .white
// Default portrait view
UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = appearance
// There are other appearances you could apply it to as well...
// UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
// UINavigationBar.appearance().compactAppearance = appearance
```

Answer (score 0):

Make like this:

```
let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
appearance.backgroundColor = .red
appearance.titleTextAttributes = [.font: 
UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20.0),
                              .foregroundColor: UIColor.white]

// Customizing our navigation bar
navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .white
navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance = appearance
navigationController?.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
```

I wrote a new article talking about it.

https://medium.com/@eduardosanti/uinavigationbar-is-black-on-ios-15-44e7852ea6f7

Comment: Hi, is there any way to change them on the storyboard, as the view controllers on the storyboard are not supposed to look like that